# Drupal how create alias

Tags: path-aliases

I am looking to create aliases.

My url is `user/uid/edit` and I want `panel/your-edit` or `panel/uid/your-edit`
How can i do that? How create alias?

When i try create alias in admin panel I have an error:
Path user/[user:uid]/edit is incorrect or user do not have access.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will  help you,

In Drupal 7 you can use these modules for your requirement

- [Extended path aliases](https://drupal.org/project/path_alias_xt)
- [Sub-pathauto (Sub-path URL Aliases)](https://drupal.org/project/subpathauto)

Answer (score 0):

In permission, check user access control and make sure that all users can "access content"

Comment: I think question was about user profiles and not content.